# The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Value*>*' , flutter cupertino date picker inside form_bloc

Tags: android, ios, flutter, forms, flutter-cupertino

I tried to following the the code from https://github.com/GiancarloCode/form_bloc/issues/64 about modify widget inside `form_bloc` using import dependencies from `select_dialog`, actually i try to implementing cupertino date picker widget inside form_bloc just like this:

[image]

I try to follow the tutorial first, but when i follow the tutorial the error alert is appear inside [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abVAA.png), and it shows: `The argument type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Value*>*'`. Anyone that know how to insert cupertino widget inside form_bloc or know how to fix the error, i really need your help to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your state `SelectFieldBlocState` doesn't contain `error` or `items`,
maybe a type of `SelectFieldBlocState` is expected there instead

for that you'll need to have a check there like

```dart
if (state is SelectFieldInitialState) {
  return GestureDetector();
}
```

here, `SelectFieldInitialState` is just a state of type `SelectFieldBlocState` having `error` and `items` like:

```dart
class SelectFieldInitialState extends SelectFieldBlocState {
  final String error;
  final List<Value> items;

  const SelectFieldInitialState({
    required this.error,
    required this.items,
  });
}
```